# Handling OData Error in client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4, dataservice

I'm consuming a At WebApi 2.2 OData v4 service in a c# client.
In the server side I'm wrapping exceptions into `Microsoft.Odata.Core.ODataError` object.

In the Microsoft OData V4 DataServiceClient client and I'm catching the exception in following block of code.

```
try
{
    //Post message to server
}
catch (DataServiceClientException ex)
{
    string result = ex.Message;
    ODataError error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result) as ODataError;
}
```

Here I'm getting null value for `error` object.
However the `result` object has following `Json` string value.

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"Custom Error","message":"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint...."
  }
}
```

**Question:**
How can I convert the `Json` string to `ODataError` object?
My requirement is to read the message property from above `Json` string like `var errmsg = error.message;` Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As I guess that you use [json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, typeof(ODataError))`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) may solve your problem.